# if/else statement with setTimeout causes flicker

Tags: javascript

I'm displaying an element on scrolling down and hiding it when scrolling up again. Without using setTimeout, this works just as expected. However, using setTimeout causes the 'display' class to be added and removed in short intervals when scrolling down. How can I avoid this while keeping the delay?

```
onscroll = function() {
  var scrollTop = document.documentElement.scrollTop || document.body.scrollTop;
  if (scrollTop > 110) {
    menuButton.classList.add('display');
  } else {
    setTimeout(function() {
      menuButton.classList.remove('display');
    }, 400);
  }
}
```

Comment: Tried using clearTimeout to cancel the setTimeout?

Comment: Yep, but that doesn't fix it.

Comment: Nervermind, setting that up correctly fixed it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The timeout was still firing from earlier events. Here is my fix:

```
onscroll = function() {
  var scrollTop = document.documentElement.scrollTop || document.body.scrollTop;
  var timer;
  if (scrollTop > 110) {
    window.clearTimeout(timer);
    menuButton.classList.add('display');
  } else {
    timer = window.setTimeout(function() {
          menuButton.classList.remove('display');
      }, 400);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to check the scroll position after the `setTimeout` executes the function. It can be different after the timeout.

EDIT: If you don't want to the timeout to be triggered more than once you can clear it with [`clearTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.clearTimeout#Example).

```
var timerId;
onscroll = function() {
  var scrollTop = document.documentElement.scrollTop || document.body.scrollTop;
  if (scrollTop > 110) {
    menuButton.classList.add('display');
    clearTimeout(timerId);
  } else {
    timerId = setTimeout(function() {
      if (!(scrollTop > 110)) {
          menuButton.classList.remove('display');
      }
    }, 400);
  }
}
```

Comment: That doesn't fix it. It seems like the else statement is executed twice just after scrolling even though the scrollTop is >110.

Comment: The `onscroll` event may trigger more than once, before `setTimeout` is triggered.

Comment: That must be it. After changing the interval from 400 to 0 it works just fine. How do I keep the interval then?

Comment: Okay, I figured it out. The timeout was still firing from earlier scroll events (since it's delayed). Cancelling the timeout did the trick.